# how to use percona tool for parsing and analyze binary logs?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, percona, mysql-5.5

I have installed percona toolkit to analyze binary logs, i read that there is a utility called pt-query-digest.

But i am not sure how to use it efficiently and does it impact any server performance or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against using pt-query-digest on your binary logs. The binary logs don't contain enough useful data. Instead turn on the slow-query-log with the following commands:

- SET GLOBAL slow_query_log_file = 'slow-queries.log';
- SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 1;
- SET GLOBAL long_query_time = 0;

If you are running Percona Server, enable more verbose logging:
 - SET GLOBAL log_slow_verbosity = full;

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.6/diagnostics/slow_extended.html

After your slow query log has about 1GB of data in it, you can turn down the logging:

- SET GLOBAL long_query_time = 10;

Then run the log through pt-query-digest as such:

`pt-query-digest slow-queries.log --limit 10`

By default it will order the output by longest execution time. You can see the stats on each query and identify which ones need optimization by running EXPLAIN on the statements.

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-query-digest.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html